# html - make column appear after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I've been playing around with HTML and I created a column that immediately appears when I open my file in a browser. I tried moving the column and row classes around but I can't figure out how to get it so that the column doesn't appear until after I select an option from the dropdown menu. I was wondering how I could fix this issue?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Display</title>
    </head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .center{
        text-align: center;
        border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    }
    {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 2000px; 
    }
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <div class ="center">
        <p><div><h1>Testing Display</h1></div><br /><p>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <form>
        <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target" onchange="display(this)"> 
            <option value="none">Choose an option</option>
            <option value="one">Option one</option> 
        </select>
        <input type=button value="Select" onclick="display()"/>
        <div id="add"></div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
        <h2>Column 1</h2>
        <p>Some text..</p>
        <div id="div"></div> 
      </div>
    </div>
        <script src="order.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Solution, call this method in onchange event of drop down list:

```
function ddlChange(){
if (document.getElementById("list").value === "one"){
        document.getElementsByClassName("column").style.display = "table-cell";
    }     
}
```

Using jQuery:

```
$("#list").change(function () {
           if($('#list option:selected').val() === "one")
               $(".column").css("display","table-cell");
 });
```

Alternatively, you can also try to add or remove a class instead of changing inline CSS value.

Comment: This implies the use of jquery, which is not in the user's posted code. This would be more of a suggestion than an answer, I would think.

Comment: Provided JavaScript implementation as well. @PaulT.

Answer (score 0):

Have the initial visibility of column to hidden.

Have a Javascript function to add a new class to column onChange. Something like this

```
function onSelect() {
  //or add id to easily access unique single element.
  var element = document.getElementByClassName("column")[0];
  element.classList.add("showCol");
} 

.column {
  visibility: hidden;
  ...
}
.showCol {
  visibility: visible;
  ...
}
```

Can also add styles and remove style onChange instead of toggling classes.